# template class with std string argument gives segmentation fault when using local array as storage

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl

Here is the program

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
   struct Node{
      T data;
      Node *next;
   };

   void setData(T data)
   {
      head = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(storage);
      head->data = data;
   }
private:
   unsigned char storage[2048];
   Node* head;
};

int main()
{
   Test<std::string> test;
   test.setData("Hello");
   return 0;
}
```

The above program compiles and also works fine when argument is of int type.
But when I set argument as std::string it crashes on - head->data = data;

Is it something I have to take care of std::string explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `head` is not initialized

Comment: Just for clarification, are you trying to implement a linked list? @Someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell the compiler to treat the array `storage` as a `Node` structure. But the data in `storage` isn't initialized in any way, it's contents is *indeterminate* and using it in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

More specifically, the members of the "structure" are not constructed or initialized, so trying to use the member `data` for anything complex will (as in your case) very likely result in crashes.

The simple solution is to use *placement `new`*

```
head = new (storage) Node;
```

Note that after placement `new` you can't `delete` the object, you need to explicitly call the destructor

```
head->~Node();
```

Comment: Also, `storage` must be aligned correctly. Better to define it, e.g, via `std::aligned_storage`.

Answer (score 1):

You operate on uninitialized memory. Especially you try to implement your own memory management, which will fail in 99% of implementations.

You can simply use `new` and `delete` in your created class and don't worry about the memory any longer.

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next;
};

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    Test() {
        head = new Node<T>();
    }

    ~Test() {
        delete head; head = nullptr;
    }

    void setData(T data) {
        if (head = nullptr) {
            head->data = data;
        }
    }
private:
    Node<T>* head = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    Test<std::string> test_string;
    Test<int> test_int;
    test_string.setData("Hello");
    test_int.setData(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Important notes:

- in the constructor of `Test`, the memory will be allocated
- for every `new`, there must be a `delete`. So please note the destructor
- for a good defensive implementation, always check, if pointers are a `nullptr`
- And for a even much better code style, PLEASE DO NOT use `using namespace std;`. If you do so, you `open` an enormously large namespace, which could collide with some of your class names or function names. This error nearly impossible to find.

disclaimer: this works on MSVC2017.

**BONUS**

For a more modern `c++`, you could use a `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next;
};

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:

    void setData(T data)
    {
        if (head = nullptr)
        {
            head->data = data;
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> head = std::make_unique<Node<T>>();
};

int main()
{
    Test<std::string> test_string;
    Test<int> test_int;
    test_string.setData("Hello");
    test_int.setData(1);
    return 0;
}
```